# “Invalid JSON string” in Google visualization API example

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw table through Google visualization API based on mysql database

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['table']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawItems);

 function drawItems(num) {
    //alert(num.value);     
  var jsonTableData = $.ajax({
  url: "gettabledata.php",
  data: "q="+num,
  dataType:"json",
  async: false
}).responseText;
```

The client side javascript code that receives the json:

```
 var tabledata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonTableData);
 var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
 table.draw(tabledata);
 }
```

This causes the following error on constructing the DataTable object (first line):

**Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON string**

This is the json (generated by the google api):

```
{"cols":[{"id":"Name","label":"Arr Name","type":"string"},{"id":"PMU","label":"PMU","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"a_b_c_Yellow"},{"v":"b"}]}]}
```

Comment: JSLint says that JSON is fine

Comment: @tymeJV yes, Json is fine but what should I do about this error?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you provided works, as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbpn2tes/). I hardcoded the data like this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['table']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawItems);

function drawItems(num) {  
    var jsonTableData = '{"cols":[{"id":"Name","label":"Arr Name","type":"string"},{"id":"PMU","label":"PMU","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"a_b_c_Yellow"},{"v":"b"}]}]}';

    var tabledata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonTableData);
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(tabledata);
}
```

This means that the JSON string you shared here is not *exactly* the same as the one being returned from your php file. Check to **make sure there are no invisible or unexpected characters** in your response.

Comment: This is the exact JSON string that I share here.

Comment: Did you try the fiddle I shared? The JSON data is copied from what you shared, and it works. I think perhaps there is a slight difference in the JSON which isn't readily apparent.

Comment: I'm sure, I copied the exact JSON string here, there is no even a slight difference. My problem is also that..